# JavaScript - Cannot Assign Value

Tags: javascript, object, reference

API is returning me a value I need to assign to a certain property in my object.

However, when I try to assign this valuee to my object, I get an error:

```
Error Getting Data
Arguments[1]
0: ReferenceError
message: "p_r is not defined"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
callee: function (err){
length: 1
__proto__: Object
```

The code where I try to assign this variable looks like this:

```
var AB = { pName:"AB", p_r:70, p_r_OK:80, logoURL:"../images/AB512.png" };
AB[p_r] = response[0].result;
```

AB object has been declared before together with p_r property. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: show the line where it is defined.

Comment: var AB = {
    pName:"AB",
    p_r:70,
    p_r_OK:80,
    logoURL:"../images/AB512.png"
};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use quotes with the array notation:

```
AB["p_r"] = response[0].result;
```

or use the dot notation

```
AB.p_r = response[0].result;
```

Otherwise the parser will think you are trying to use a variable named `p_r`

Comment: This is better than my answer. In a matter of fact, Douglas Crockford recommends the dot notation over the array notation.

Comment: @user3518823, expand on _"no success"_ are you getting the same error, a different error, or is something else happening

Answer (score 4):

Is p_r a variable or is it the name of the property?

If p_r is the name of the property, you should do the assignment with '', like:

```
AB['p_r'] = response[0].result;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`AB['p_r'] = response[0].result;`
OR

```
AB["p_r"] = response[0].result; OR
AB.p_r = response[0].result;
```